Sometimes I stand up, Sometimes I lay down, I wait patiently for you to talk. What am I?
Sometimes I stand up,
Sometimes I lay down,
Often I flash on and off and ...,
Nowadays, a rodent is often nearby,
I wait patiently for you to “talk”.
What am I?

Clarification:  “Often I flash on and off and ...” means the entire thing flashes not just part of it.

My tongue... Or maybe that old phone (receiver) on my old table.

You are a

 Cursor

Sometimes I stand up,
Sometimes I lay down,

 Two common cursor styles are a vertical bar or an underscore.

Often I flash on and off and ...,

 Blinking cursors are common.

Nowadays, a rodent is often nearby,

 A mouse pointer may be near the cursor.

I wait patiently for you to “talk”.

 The cursor sits there waiting for you to enter text.


You are a

 cell phone

Sometimes I stand up,

 when held to an ear

Sometimes I lay down,

 on the desk not in use

Often I flash on and off and ...,

 when a notification comes in

Nowadays, a rodent is often nearby,

 computer mouse on the same desk

I wait patiently for you to “talk”.

 that's what phones are for

